# MDN String.prototype.repeat polyfill - How can 'this' have value null?

Tags: javascript, polyfills

In the [MDN doc for String.prototype.repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat#Polyfill) the polyfill has this line of code:

```
if (!String.prototype.repeat) {
  String.prototype.repeat = function(count) {
    'use strict';
    if (this == null)
      throw new TypeError('can\'t convert ' + this + ' to object');
```

How is it possible for this to be null?

Comment: note that `undefined == null` is also `true` when checking with `==` instead of `===`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to execute a function with another context. Most JavaScript functions are designed to be generic, which is to say that it will work with most variable types.

```
String.prototype.repeat.call(1, 2); // -> "11"
String.prototype.repeat.call({}, 2); // -> "[object Object][object Object]"
```

Because of this, a simple check is put in place to make sure no-one tries executing it with the context of `null` or `undefined`

```
String.prototype.repeat.call(null, 2); // TypeError
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```js
String.prototype.repeat.call()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const test = 'test'.repeat;
test();
```

Comment: Unlike other OO languages, in Javascript the context at the point of calling the code effects the value of 'this'. In the answer by Andrey, the method has been captured into a variable as a function. Invoking that function is no longer in the context of the original object, so 'this' is no longer the original object.